# Call ALL children methods of a class from another class

Tags: c#, inheritance, methods, multiple-inheritance

Lets say that i have a "Timer" class with a method that every 1 second is called, and it calls another method in the class "Gear":

```
public class Timer
{
    public void OnTick()
    {
        Gear.Update();
    }
}

public class Gear
{
    public static void Update() { }
}
```

This kinda works, but it's only called on the base class.
The method "Update" should be called in all the childrens of "Gear":
e.g:

```
public class AnotherClass : Gear
{
    public override void Update() { // do stuff }
}
public class YetAnotherClass : Gear
{
    public override void Update() { // do stuff }
}
public class AndAnotherClass : Gear
{
    public override void Update() { // do stuff }
}
```

How can i do this?

Comment: So you want to call all instances of all subclasses of Gear? Sounds like you want to run your code in some sort of container.

Comment: Sore object reference in a collection, then iterate through them and call Update()

Comment: You code doesn't make sense. You call `Gear.Update()` like a static method, but define it as an instance method.

Comment: That's my problem. I have to call it without instancing, and i have no idea how :/

Comment: No idea what the bigger picture is here, but there certainly has to be a better approach.  Try stepping back and asking a question about what you really want, from a higher level, as any answer to the question above is going to lead to trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for the code to work the way you want, you'd need to do something like this (I would worry about a memory leak):

```
public abstract class Gear
{
    readonly static List<Gear> gears = new List<Gear>();

    public Gear()
    {
        gears.Add(this);
    }

    public static void Update()
    {
        foreach (var gear in gears)
            gear._Update();
    }

    protected abstract void _Update();
}


public sealed class Gear1 :  Gear
{
    protected override void _Update()
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}

public sealed class Gear2 : Gear
{
    protected override void _Update()
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}

public sealed class Gear3 : Gear
{
    protected override void _Update()
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}


public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var timer = 
          new Timer(o => Gear.Update(), null, 0, SOME_INTERVAL);                       
}
```

However, you *might* be better off by defining the base case thusly:

```
public abstract class Gear
{
    public abstract void Update();
}
```

And then define a collection class:

```
public sealed class GearCollection : List<Gear>
{        
    public void Update()
    {
        foreach (var gear in this)
            gear.Update();
    }
}
```

And then

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var gears = new GearCollection();

    //add gear instancs to gears

    var timer = new Timer(o => gears.Update(), null, 0, SOME_INTERVAL);            
}
```

Comment: While being reasonable I don't see how this code satisfies "I have to call it without instancing" (I have absolutely  no idea what actual restrictions are but code it this post definitely requires instantiating objects). You may want to work with OP on clarifying question so answer actually answers it.

Comment: Great hack!  "*might*" is an understatement.